# Google API to find the search count

Tags: linux, api, sed, awk

When I google for something, I get the count.

Results 1 - 10 of about 800

Is there any API or something like that to capture the number "800"?
I have a database of a few thousand words and I want the google count against it.

Comment: A relevant forum: http://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-search-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google have a [AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/samples.html) with this example: [Number of Search Results](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#large_result_set)

Comment: The property name is "cursor" with a member called "estimatedResultCount" and it's documented here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GSearch and http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje

Answer (score 0):

There well could be an API, but until it's found, why not just sent the query and scrape the resulting page?

```
wget --output-document=- http://www.google.com/search?q=the+word | grep "Results 1 - 10 of about" | awk  etc...
```

Comment: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

Comment: lynx -source http://google.com/search?q=india | grep "of about <b>" # The number that I am looking for is immediately after the "of about <b>" part. How do awk it? # </b> of about <b>479,000,000</b>