# Google API, or another search provider API, to get search result count in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, search

I saw this [**Stack Overflow Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079871/google-api-to-find-the-search-count) but I cannot find the answer to the following question:

is there a way to use a `Google API`, or another search provider api, to get the count of a web search?

i.e. get the number of results  given a search query?

Note: I'm only interested in the count of results not the single results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google API mentioned in the referenced question is deprecated.

You should use the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) - and there in the [manual](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list) you can find that the JSON-formatted answer returns also the total count of the results (JSON key named `totalResults`)